# Retrieving the value from the database and assigning it to different textboxes having a delimeter in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
 d.field1 = txt1.Text.Trim() + "$" + txt2.Text.Trim() +
 "$" + txt3.Text.Trim() + "$" + txt4.Text.Trim();
```

> This above code suggest that the values of the textbox are been stored in the database combining all the textbox using a delimeter **$**.
>   Field1 column in the database is some what have the value as **a$b$c$d.**
>   Now I need to retrieve the same value from the database and assign it to particular textbox as.

```
Txt5.text = a;
Txt6.text=b;
Txt7.text = c;
Txt8.Text = d;
```

How can I do this ?? I am planning to write a `stored procedure along with data access object and value object`. First of all I have inserted the values into the database now I need to retrieve.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
string t = "a$b$c$d";

string[] temp  = t.Split('$');

txt1.Text = temp[0] !=null ? temp[0] : "" ;
```

just made a [Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/8Hu21p)